# Error on Import Data Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

I use SQL Server Import and Export Wizard for import data from an excel sheet. 
And these are the errors:

> Messages Error 0xc020901c: Data Flow Task 1: There was an error with
>   Source - Sheet1$.Outputs[Excel Source Output].Columns[PtnDescription]
>   on Source - Sheet1$.Outputs[Excel Source Output]. The column status
>   returned was: "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no
>   match in the target code page.".  (SQL Server Import and Export
>   Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc020902a: Data Flow Task 1: The "Source -
>   Sheet1$.Outputs[Excel Source Output].Columns[PtnDescription]" failed
>   because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on
>   "Source - Sheet1$.Outputs[Excel Source
>   Output].Columns[PtnDescription]" specifies failure on truncation. A
>   truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified
>   component.  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0047038:
>   Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The
>   PrimeOutput method on Source - Sheet1$ returned error code 0xC020902A.
>   The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called
>   PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the
>   component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing. 
>   There may be error messages posted before this with more information
>   about the failure.

And the columns thta I have [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWfgF.jpg)

What can I do?

Comment: `The "Source - Sheet1$.Outputs[Excel Source Output].Columns[PtnDescription]" failed because truncation occurred` that means that the `PtnDescription` table field is too short. Increase it so it can accept the largest description string in your file

Answer (score 0):

That means there are unicode characters in your Excel source data that cannot be converted to the the target column(s) in SQL Server [varchar() or char()].  In SQL Server you need to use nvarchar() or char() columns to store unicode data you want to import from Excel.

The import wizard is throwing an error and letting you know (albeit mystically) that is the problem.

UPDATE: Disregard this, Panagotis is correct, you have need to widen your target, not change the data type.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So, it's nothing related to the SourceType? Plus, the DB has only nvarchar (255) and for that column[PtnDescription] is nvarchar[1000]

Comment: The error complains about *truncation*, not conversion. This isn't about Unicode. Increase the field size. There is nothing mystical, the error mentions truncation and the affected column.

Comment: I have this same error with Excel 2016 and SQL Server 2014. The longest string in the column it is complaining about is 332 characters, and I've expanded the target column to 512. This did not help. Further, if I delete the column entirely, the file loads fine, so I know it has something to do with the characters in that column. In my case, I think it IS related to Unicode data (although the database is Unicode, so I don't know why that would be an issue).